# Acrescentar option ao select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Boa tarde!

HTML

```
<label class="labelPequeno">Cidade</label>
<select class="typeTextMedio" name="cidade" id="cidade" required>
    <option value="" selected>Selecione a cidade</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
option = document.createElement( "option" );
option.value = "28510";
option.text = "Muriaé";
option.selected;
$("#cidade").add( option );
```

A ideia é criar um `option` no `select` com `id="cidade"`, porem não está acrescentando.

O que está errado?

Tentei assim também mas não deu certo:

```
$('#cidade').append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value","<?php echo $cidade["id"]; ?>")
            .text("<?php echo $cidade["nome"]; ?>")
            .attr("seleted","selected");
```

Também assim:

```
$("#cidade").append('<option value="<?php echo $cidade["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $cidade["nome"]; ?></option>');
```

Não funcionou!

Comment: Use `append` ao invéz de `add`.

Comment: dá uma olhada no final da pergunta

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/PetrusStarken/33rpxLf9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
$('#cidade').append('<option value="<?php echo $cidade["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $cidade["nome"]; ?></option>');
```

Ou

```
$('#cidade').append($('<option>', {value:<?php echo $cidade["id"]; ?>, text:'<?php echo $cidade["nome"];?>'}));
```

Ou

```
$('#mySelect').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",<?php echo $cidade["id"]; ?>).text(<?php echo $cidade["nome"];?>));
```

**Veja essse exemplo**: http://jsfiddle.net/wBrLa/82/

Comment: deu certo mas preciso enviar ele selected

Comment: @CarlosRocha Veja os outros exemplo e se ainda não conseguir, veja o link

Comment: Achei o erro: estava escrevendo seleted em vez de selected.

Comment: :) .. acontece rsrs